# Visual studio 2010 can't find definition of anything except local variables for a solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have installed a fresh copy of windows 8.1. Installed VS2010 and Visual Assist latest trial version. Before installing a fresh copy of windows VS2010 was finding definition/ references/ call hierarchy of everything correctly for that solution. Now it shows
`A definition for the symbol "OBJECT" could not be found.`

Here `OBJECT` is the variable/function of which I want to find the definition/reference for. Visual assist works find though. I disabled visual assist from extension manager. But it doesn't work either. It works fine with the older versions of the same solution. I have added some projects as reference of other projects. I don't know if it is the cause of the problem. Thanks.

EDIT: The solution consists of 13 C++ projects.

Comment: can you give a real example? is it a compilation problem? a linker problem?

Comment: There is no compilation error. No linker error. I can run the project successfully. I just can't use the features of finding definition/references/hierarchy etc.

Comment: It is problem with Intellisense that has got stuck for that particular solution. It may help if you order it to recreate its database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is problem with Intellisense that has got stuck for that particular solution.

Microsoft has [sort of unhelpful msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235519%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) articles about it. In practice it gets sometimes stuck and it may help if you order (or enforce by deleteing) it to recreate its databases.